# What mean"subject" in the sentence?

Tags: subjects, grammatical-roles

I have a problem in this sentence
I cannot understand the meaning of "subject" in the sentence:

Guthrie has also demonstrated that the landscape must have been **subject** to intense and continuous winds, especially in winter

As the Logman dictionary, "subject" can play roles as a noun, an adjective, and a verb, therefore this can different meanings. this word, subject, cannot be a verb because if it plays a role as a verb it should have been written in the past form.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Where did you get that sentence from? Did you copy it from somewhere or you wrote it yourself?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Try looking up *subject to* as a phrase.

Comment: Thank you. I copy this text from a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### subject to

1. affected by or possibly affected by (something)
2. likely to do, have, or suffer from (something)
3. dependent on something else to happen or be true

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject%20to)

In the example sentence, definition 1 is in play. The landscape is affected by something, namely "intense and continuous winds."

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, "must have been subject to" means "must have been exposed to" and "must have been under".
If you translate the sentence word-by-word in order, you can guess the meaning.
"subject" is not a verb in this sentence. "have been" is the verb.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "**subject**" is an adjective: From the OED

> Subject (adjective):
>
> **II. Expressing a relationship of liability, exposure, or dependence between a person or thing and a state, condition, or experience. Chiefly in predicative use, with *to***.
>
> **4.b Exposed to violent treatment, damaging weather, or the like.**
>
> 1726   G. Leoni tr. L. B. Alberti Archit. I. 7   *The Isle of Lemnos..being very subject to Lightning.*
>
> 1907   Broad Views Feb. 143   *Ferry boats cross 90 miles of the Michigan Lake,—subject to storms quite as violent as those which afflict the Channel.*
>
> 2003   E. Mumford Redesigning Human Syst. iv. 58   *The family of the ‘black leg’, who remained at work when others were on strike, was subject to abuse and ignominy.*